# Solving a matrix equation involving trace and determinant

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations, trace

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$. Consider the following set :
$$
E_n=\{A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})| \mathrm{Tr}(A)=\det(A)\}
$$

My goal is to characterize $E_n$ for any $n$.

I have already found a solution for $n=2$ :

Let A be a matrix in $E_2$ and let's call $\chi_A$ its characteristic polynomial.
Since we have $\mathrm{Tr}(A)=\det(A)=\alpha$, then $\chi_A=X^2-\alpha X+\alpha=(X-\lambda_1)(X-\lambda_2)$

With $\lambda_{1/2}=\frac{\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha(\alpha-4)}}{2}$

We distinguish four cases :

**If** $\alpha=0$ then $A$ is similar to
$\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & a\\
  0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

**If** $\alpha=4$ then $A$ is similar to
$\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & a\\
  0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

**Else** $A$ is similar to
$\begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda_1 & 0\\
  0 & \lambda_2
\end{pmatrix}$

Do you have any idea on how to proceed for $n=3$ or bigger ?

*n.b. This question is entirely from me, I invented it. I do not even know if there is a nice answer to this problem.*